# Extending ActionView Renderere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I am trying to create a gem to extend Rails ActionView Renderer to print an HTML comment with the partial view name bring rendered.

I tried the normal way:

```
module MyGem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer 'mygem.initialize' do
      ::ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
        ::ActionView::Renderer.send :include, MyGem::ViewRenderer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then in mygem/lib/view_renderer.rb:

```
module MyGem
  module ViewRenderer
    module InstanceMethods
      def render(context, options)
        puts "here" # Just to test it was included and it doesn't print
        if options.key?(:partial)
          render_partial(context, options)
        else
          render_template(context, options)
        end
      end
    end

    def self.included(base)
      base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I use `render` from my views, the test line added doesn't work.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it in the past, maybe it will help.

```
module MyModule

  def self.included(base)
    def render
     #do stuff 
    end
  end
end

ActionController::Base.send :include, MyModule
```

Then just require the file

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it extends ActionController render method, not ActionView. Tried to do the same to override ActionView's but in vain.